# Applying timezone to date format not working

Tags: java, android, datetime

In my Android app I have a string like this, `String date = "2016-09-24T06:24:01Z";`

I use this code to turn it into a nicer looking date format:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
DateFormat formatted = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

Date result = dateFormat.parse(date);
dateString = formatted.format(result);
```

However it's not applying the timezone. I've tried setting it on both `dateFormat` and `formatted` and no matter what I do it still comes back with `6:24 AM`.

Shouldn't `TimeZone.getDefault()` be looking at the timezone on the device running the app and adjusting the time accordingly?

Comment: are you using `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: Yes it's java.util.Date

Comment: `java.util.Date` has no time zone†. It represents `UTC/GMT (no time zone offset)`.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

As your are using `java.util.date` which have no `Time Zone`. It represent `UTC/GMT` no Time Zone offset. See below thing.

so change this line

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

to this

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

or this

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: But how do I end up getting the `dateString` result to show the the time using whatever the timezone of the device is?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the current time zone:

```
TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
tzone.setDefault(tzone);
```

If you do not know the current timezone:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long milliDiff = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
// Got local offset, now loop through available timezone id(s).
String [] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
String name = null;
for (String id : ids) {
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
  if (tz.getRawOffset() == milliDiff) {
    // Found a match.
    name = id;
    break;
  }
}

TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(name);
tzone.setDefault(tzone);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the current time though. I want to convert `String date = "2016-09-24T06:24:01Z";` into a nice string, and have that result use the local timezone.